# What is the the name of the mother's son?

Tags: riddle

### Say the name of the mother's son

A mother had a son who had three children. 
He named the first one Myko because he was a psycho.

The second one he named Jim because he had an interest in sims.

The third one was the worst, he thought he might burst. 
His name was so funny, he named him Micklunny!

Now that you know all their names, but one. 
What is the name of the mother's son.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "What"

Is the name of the mother's son, since

> there is no question mark at the end of the sentence stating this as fact.

Comment: You got it correct.

Comment: i figured his name was "son" because the first sentence just said "A mother had son" not "A mother had a son".